# How to distribute private android application to specific devices?

Tags: android, deployment

How can I deploy an APK for android that is only available for the devices I specify beforehand?

I would like to a host a private application that is only available to workers inside the company and only for the devices that are owned by the company.

I know I can do this with Google Play, but that requires a G-Suite/Workspace subscription we do not have.

I would like to continuously deploy new versions and the devices to update automatically.

Are there any custom marketplaces that allow this? Anything else?

Comment: Well, you can look at Knox if you are using Samsung devices, it has a free license version that should be enough for simply updating devices. I'll explain bit more, you can use Knox to enforce a policy on a device. You can enforce your company policy and then in your app you can check if the device is using that specific policy, allow the app to run, otherwise, don't.

Comment: @DanBaruch Sounds good. We will use Samsung Active Tabs. Although it seems it requires commercial license of some sort. It would not be a problem depending on the price.

Comment: Hmm, from my usage of Knox, the premium license gives more functionality, but I don't think you'll need any of them for the scenario you describe.

Comment: @DanBaruch Are you talking about the partner program? ( https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/knox-licenses.htm )

Comment: Talking about these lines: *KPE license types
The Knox SDK and Knox Tizen SDK for Wearables use the Knox Platform for Enterprise (KPE) license. This license is permission-based, with these variants providing access to different free and paid features:

KPE Standard—Provides permissions to call APIs that manage device features like network connections, user accounts, location, simple kiosking, data encryption, and security restrictions. This is a free license.* from the link you provided. You need to register there and you are good to go

Comment: @DanBaruch I applied for the partner program, got approved, generated a development and commercial license key, uploaded the APK to the partner site, but I can't do anything else. The Knox dashboard does not allow me to do anything, everything is disabled. (but I can see the licence keys from the partner program)

Comment: You should use their SDK. You activate the license through code and then you have access to all the functions they have to offer. Options available: https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/packages.html

Comment: Functions permissions: https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/license-permissions.htm

Comment: Activating through code: https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/tutorial-activate-license.htm
I've divided it to multiple comments to make it look somewhat oredered

Comment: @DanBaruch But, for now, I don't want their SDK (also, I am using Xamarin). All I want is to deploy the APK to the device.

Comment: I see, well in that case the solution isn't good enough. I thought their SDK is useable to you, I do know though, that using Knox UI you can create a policy and you can apply it to your device (You'll have to find out how on your own though, I haven't looked much into it) and maybe using that policy might help you progress with your needs